# docker Error processing tar file(exit status 1): no space left on device

Tags: linux, docker

I'm continuously getting this the following error when try to build a docker image:

```
Step 6/8 : COPY . /app
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /app/.git/objects/81/4f44ad8c3bef33a0bb0729bee8f251a327d9a8: no space left on device
```

this is sort of fixed if I use:

```
docker system prune
```

I'm delete the previous image using:

```
docker rmi <my_image>
```

The problem is that this makes the whole testing very tedious, since I have to create the images from scratch after each change.

```
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my_image   latest              12b2499ac23d        52 minutes ago      6.67GB
```

That is the image I have to delete and create each time. I still have space left on the machine so really not finding what is the issue here:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

from df -ih

[image]

Comment: `COPY . /app` is the context just contain a Dockerfile or it might be the case that the current directory context is large enough. as the image is ` 6.67GB`

Comment: @Adiii  what do you mean with the "directory context"?

Comment: you are copying `.` the whole working directory where the Dockerfile is, so check the working directory size.

Comment: @adiii directory size is about 1.2 Gb with what should I compare it to know that there is no space left?

Comment: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-devops/issues/41

Comment: docker system info | grep  "Docker Root Dir", usually "/var/ib/docker". Can you provide a list of abandoned images? it looks like you have a lot of them, "docker images -f dangling=true", so clean them all, "docker images prune -f".

Comment: also good link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes

Comment: @Dmitrii I added a screen shot after running "docker images -f dangling=true" it seems there is not, actually

Comment: Can you provide a full list of images? you can grep result by image name..

Comment: Also 6gb is too much for an image, it looks like you have a lot of unused source code inside an image, you need to update a build scenario. copy can be used in cases like python code, where a part of source code can be excluded from the image by using .dockerignore

Comment: I have only to images, that one and an Ubuntu one. Yeah, I meassed up one directory and have adictional 500mb on .git but also have some ML models that I need, that explains part of the size

Comment: That's it! use .dockerignore to exclude .git folder from copy command. ML models is just a part of source code, use docker multi-stage build to train the model in the first image and upload the result to the target one. Target image must have only the needed data!

Comment: Can you check Inode usage `df -ih`

Comment: @Dmitrii  I do fine tunning of the model as a service, I need it. I'm trying now ignoring git folder

Comment: @mchawre I just added that screenshot to the question

Comment: @Dmitrii is 4Gb now

Comment: Ok, that's all. You need to read an article about the storage system in Docker, especially about "build context" and layers. During the build using a copy command, you double the size +  docker requires additional info to store intermediate layers and info. That is why a prune command helps you, it remove everything from the root. Your storage is not big, and the image is too big, so almost nothing to do) You can attach one more drive and move docker root or a build context there, you can move ML data to an external source and download it during the build and execution and so on.

Comment: @luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez I have answered You question in Answer Box. I think this will help you lot :-)

Answer (score 5):

you can use a small but useful command:

```html
docker image prune
```

to delete all the unused container.It will free your needed memory.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to exclude all unnecessary files from the context?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file